# Javascript regex match fail

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Can someone explain why this does not work? (I am using Chrome Developer Console)

```
pattern  
-> "/Xmp\.MP\.RegionInfo\/MPRI:Regions/"
key
-> "Xmp.MP.RegionInfo/MPRI:Regions[1]"
key.search(pattern)
-> -1
key.search(/Xmp\.MP\.RegionInfo\/MPRI:Regions/)
-> -1
"Xmp.MP.RegionInfo/MPRI:Regions[1]".search(pat)
-> -1
"Xmp.MP.RegionInfo/MPRI:Regions[1]".search(/Xmp\.MP\.RegionInfo\/MPRI:Regions/)
-> 0
```

It make absolutely no sense to me that the search does not match if i use the variables....

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior: `key.search(/Xmp\.MP\.RegionInfo\/MPRI:Regions/)` outputs `-1`. I get `0` instead, as is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `pattern` is a String in your first example, it needs to be a `RegExp` object:

```
var pattern = /Xmp\.MP\.RegionInfo\/MPRI:Regions/
var key = "Xmp.MP.RegionInfo/MPRI:Regions[1]"

key.search(pattern); // equals 0
```

If you want to convert a string to a regex, use the `RegExp` constructor (but remove the slashes):

```
var pattern = new RegExp("Xmp\.MP\.RegionInfo\/MPRI:Regions");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CpEjA/

Comment: No it doesn't, but it is in the question. Can't explain it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example pattern appears to be a string. You need it to be a RegExp object.

Answer (score 0):

In first case your pattern is wrapped in quotes, so it is string. In second case it is without quotes -> it is RegExp object.